# How to check certain NFC type capability of the host android device

Tags: java, android, nfc

I'm making a simple app that detects the android device where the app runs on supports NFC type-f(FeliCa) and its HCE/SE encryption capability.

Also, I want to know, if the host device doesn't support NFC type-f or its HCE/SE encryption capability, whether this problem is due to hardware limitation(lack of host NFC chip support), or software limitation(e.g. the current ROM doesn't support it), and 
 if it's software limitation(that can be fixed, even it requires the root permission, lack of NFC chip firmware license) I want to know the exact reason so that I can solve that problem.

But I don't know how to check the host capability of certain NFC type and there's no mention of Android API to check a certain NFC type suppport.

Comment: If you go on google and search for it, the answer can be found. I just tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to detect if 'NFC-F' is supported use:

[PackageManager.FEATURE_NFC_HOST_CARD_EMULATION_NFCF](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#FEATURE_NFC_HOST_CARD_EMULATION_NFCF)

as in:

```
 if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
         PackageManager.FEATURE_NFC_HOST_CARD_EMULATION_NFCF)) {
    // has feature
 }
```

This was discovered by checking [Android Open Source Project - 
Host Card Emulation of FeliCa](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/felica).

The AOSP documentation states that **HCE FeliCa requires NFC hardware that supports the NFC-F (JIS 6319-4) standard.**

Further along the AOSP documentation references the Android Compatibility Test Suite, the specific [Android 9.0 test set for NFC can be found here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/android-9.0.0_r30/apps/CtsVerifier/src/com/android/cts/verifier/nfc/) and has a specific set of tests of [HCE FeliCa](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/android-9.0.0_r30/apps/CtsVerifier/src/com/android/cts/verifier/nfc/hcef/). As it is a test suite, additional code for testing communications with the card appear to be within.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to check that SE encryption can be used by NFC type-f also?

Comment: I mean, Secure Element(SIM SE, eSE, etc.).

Comment: I'm still unclear as to your meaning of Secure Element. From my understanding the HCE FeliCa support specification has some form of security. It may be best to review the [documentation on FeliCa](https://www.sony.net/Products/felica/business/tech-support/index.html) especially the last one at the bottom of the page which covers Android applications.

Comment: I was able to figure it out for Secure Element. I was talking about this(http://seek-for-android.github.io/javadoc/V4.0.0/org/simalliance/openmobileapi/SEService.html). I was want not only HCE but SIM SE(or eSE) support. I now know this is a separate specification.

Comment: BTW, is there any way to just know if the device supports NFC-F itself(even if without HCE capability)?